# Eloquent Javascript Chapter 11 (3rd Edition) paradox?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm currently working through the 'Eloquent Javascript' 3rd Edition, currently at the final chapter, but I'm still not quite get the Chapter 11 'connections' requestType code. (you can see the whole chapter at: https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html#c_68Z9trrpeS)

When using 'everywhere' method, each nest will have its own 'connection' property, but in the beginning only 1 nest has it, it then broadcast connections to all nearby neighbors, but when the neighbors received it, they don't have the 'connections' property setup yet (because only the source nest has it at the moment), how does 'requestType()' method assign a new 'connections' from null?

Here is the code:

```js
requestType("connections", (nest, {name, neighbors},
                            source) => {
  let connections = nest.state.connections;
  if (JSON.stringify(connections.get(name)) ==
      JSON.stringify(neighbors)) return;
  connections.set(name, neighbors);
  broadcastConnections(nest, name, source);
});

function broadcastConnections(nest, name, exceptFor = null) {
  for (let neighbor of nest.neighbors) {
    if (neighbor == exceptFor) continue;
    request(nest, neighbor, "connections", {
      name,
      neighbors: nest.state.connections.get(name)
    });
  }
}

everywhere(nest => {
  nest.state.connections = new Map;
  nest.state.connections.set(nest.name, nest.neighbors);
  broadcastConnections(nest, nest.name);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First, let's take a look at the everywhere method declaration in [crow-tech.js](https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/crow-tech.js)

```
everywhere(f) {
  for (let node of Object.values(this.nodes)) f(node);
}
```

All this does is that it takes a callback function `f` and then for each node/nest in our network, we invoke `f`, passing each node/nest as a parameter.

Now, looking at this invocation of everywhere:

```
everywhere(nest => {
  nest.state.connections = new Map;
  nest.state.connections.set(nest.name, nest.neighbors);
  broadcastConnections(nest, nest.name);
});
```

The anonymous function below is actually passed to everywhere as f.

```
nest => {
      nest.state.connections = new Map;
      nest.state.connections.set(nest.name, nest.neighbors);
      broadcastConnections(nest, nest.name);
    }
```

So we're saying, for each node/nest, we want to instantiate a new Map and set it to its connections property of its state. Also, we will first add one entry into that Map with the key being the name of the nest and the value being its immediate neighbors.

Now, let's talk about `broadcastConnections(nest, nest.name)`

```
function broadcastConnections(nest, name, exceptFor = null) {
  for (let neighbor of nest.neighbors) {
    if (neighbor == exceptFor) continue;
    request(nest, neighbor, "connections", {
      name,
      neighbors: nest.state.connections.get(name),
    });
  }
}
```

We can see that we are iterating through each of our nest's immediate neighbors and invoking this request function below:

```
function request(nest, target, type, content) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let done = false;
    function attempt(n) {
      nest.send(target, type, content, (failed, value) => {
        done = true;
        if (failed) reject(failed);
        else resolve(value);
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (done) return;
        else if (n < 3) attempt(n + 1);
        else reject(new Timeout("Timed out"));
      }, 250);
    }
    attempt(1);
  });
}
```

This request function then invokes a send method of the node/nest from crow-tech.js file

```
send(to, type, message, callback) {
  let toNode = this[$network].nodes[to];
  if (!toNode || !this.neighbors.includes(to))
    return callback(new Error(`${to} is not reachable from ${this.name}`));
  let handler = this[$network].types[type];
  if (!handler) return callback(new Error("Unknown request type " + type));
  if (Math.random() > 0.03)
    setTimeout(() => {
      try {
        handler(toNode, ser(message), this.name, (error, response) => {
          setTimeout(() => callback(error, ser(response)), 10);
        });
      } catch (e) {
        callback(e);
      }
    }, 10 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
}
```

In the send method, you can see that we are eventually invoking `setTimeout()`, this function basically will put a function onto the event or message queue. This article provides more info on event loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

In our case, the handler function inside the send method is the one that was defined by this function:

```
requestType("connections", (nest, { name, neighbors }, source) => {
  let connections = nest.state.connections;
  if (JSON.stringify(connections.get(name)) === JSON.stringify(neighbors))
    return;
  connections.set(name, neighbors);
  broadcastConnections(nest, name, source);
});
```

More specifically, the handler function is this anonymous function expression:

```
(nest, { name, neighbors }, source) => {
      let connections = nest.state.connections;
      if (JSON.stringify(connections.get(name)) === JSON.stringify(neighbors))
        return;
      connections.set(name, neighbors);
      broadcastConnections(nest, name, source);
    }
```

To finally tie everything together, the reason that connections would never be null is because the anonymous function inside send method that invokes handler is actually on the event or message queue. Functions in the event or message queue will only execute when the current stack of event loop is empty.

These two lines which gets invoked for each node/nest are all on the stack already:

```
  nest.state.connections = new Map;
  nest.state.connections.set(nest.name, nest.neighbors);
```

That is why by the time the handler for "connections" type is invoked, connections for each node/nest is a valid Map instance with at least 1 entry.

Answer (score 0):

Under the covers, broadcastConnections() uses request() that performs asyncrounous actions. Thus, any actions triggered by broadcastConnections() happen in the next "tick" of the event loop, which means that by that time every nest has its own Map collection.